# Syntax Error (Missing Operator) in query expression with Multiple Inner Join in C# MS Access

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am using Inner Join to Join 3 Tables. But when I execute this, I got error

> Syntax Error (Missing Operator) in query expression 'a.Group_ID = b.Group_ID INNER JOIN VendorList AS c ON a.Vendor_Id = c.Vendor_I'

How do I use multiple inner joins in C# with MS Access?

```
str = "Select a.ID, b.Group_Name, a.Voucher_No, a.Bill_No, a.Date, c.Vendor_Name, a.Amount FROM BillTable a INNER JOIN GroupName AS b ON a.Group_ID = b.Group_ID INNER JOIN VendorList AS c ON a.Vendor_Id = c.Vendor_Id ";
                da = new OleDbDataAdapter(str, cn);
```

Answer (score 3):

That syntax, while accepted by any database more powerful than Access, is not quite right when you are dealing with JET Sql. In this case you need to add round brackets around each join group to help the JET parser understand the query.

So you need to write this one instead

```
str = @"Select a.ID, b.Group_Name, a.Voucher_No, a.Bill_No, a.[Date], c.Vendor_Name, a.Amount 
      FROM ((BillTable a INNER JOIN GroupName AS b ON a.Group_ID = b.Group_ID) 
                        INNER JOIN VendorList AS c ON a.Vendor_Id = c.Vendor_Id) ";
```

Note that the most external pair of round brackets are not really required. I put them there just to show how to add them if more joins are required.

Also I think that a.Date will be the cause of another exception because [Date is a reserved keyword](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2?ocmsassetid=ha010030643&correlationid=074fef88-eec4-45aa-82cd-b67d7c988eb9&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#duplicate=0). You will get a syntax error again. You can avoid it adding square brackets around Date like in *a.[Date]*